# using pptxgenjs, add an image that takes the full size of the slide

Tags: pptxgenjs

PptxGenJS allows creating a Powerpoint file by scripting.
https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/

we can add an image as follows:

```
slide.addImage({ path: "images/chart_world_peace_near.png", x:..., y:..., w:..., h:...});
```

I need to resize the image to the full size of the slide, with the aspect ratio. So, I need to know the size of the image and the size of the slide, as follows:

```
scaled_image_width = slide_width
scaled_image_height = image_height * scaled_image_width / image_width;
if (scaled_image_height > slide_height) {
  scaled_image_height = slide_height
  scaled_image_width = image_width * scaled_image_height / image_height;
}
```

However, I don't see a way in PptxGenJS to get the size of the image and the size of the slide. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add background to slide using below

```
var pptx1 = new PptxGenJS();
var slide = pptx1.addSlide();
```

After adding slide you can add background to it

```
slide.background = {path:"Image URL"};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string format for width, for example: w: '100%', this will asign slide width to image.